# MixItUp não mostra os elementos

Tags: html, css, filter, jquery-plugins

Boa Noite,
Venho tentando utilizar o plugin MixItUp para modificar as thumbs de uma galeria de imagem, porém, as imagens ficam sempre sem mostrar (como inicialmente o plugin pede), não consigo identificar qual o motivo do plugin não mostrar os elementos, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eva7b90u/

```js
$(function(){
    $('#Grid').mixitup();
});
```

```css
#Grid .mix{

 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mixitup/latest/jquery.mixitup.min.js?v=2.1.9"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4 btn-group hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm filter" data-filter="all">
                  Todos
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm filter" data-filter=".category-2">
                  Trilho
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" data-filter=".category-1">
                  Varão
                </button>
              </div> 

<div class="col-sm-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">
        
            <!-- thumb navigation carousel items -->
          <ul class="list-inline mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark-3" id="Grid">


          <li class="hvr-pulse-grow mix category-1" data-cat="1"> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
            <img src="modal/cortinas/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cortina">
          </a></li>

          <li class="hvr-pulse-grow mix category-1" data-cat="1"> <a id="carousel-selector-1">
            <img src="modal/cortinas/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cortina">
          </a></li>

          <li class="hvr-pulse-grow mix category-1" data-cat="1"> <a id="carousel-selector-2">
            <img src="modal/cortinas/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cortina">
          </a></li>

          <li class="hvr-pulse-grow mix category-1" data-cat="1"> <a id="carousel-selector-3">
            <img src="modal/cortinas/4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cortina">
          </a></li>

          <li class="hvr-pulse-grow mix category-1" data-cat="1"> <a id="carousel-selector-4">
            <img src="modal/cortinas/5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cortina">
          </a></li>

          <li class="hvr-pulse-grow mix category-2" data-cat="2"> <a id="carousel-selector-5">
            <img src="modal/cortinas/6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cortina">
          </a></li>

          <li class="hvr-pulse-grow mix category-2" data-cat="2"> <a id="carousel-selector-6">
            <img src="modal/cortinas/7.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cortina">
          </a></li>

          <li class="hvr-pulse-grow mix category-2" data-cat="2"> <a id="carousel-selector-7">
            <img src="modal/cortinas/8.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cortina">
          </a></li>

          <li class="hvr-pulse-grow mix category-2" data-cat="2"> <a id="carousel-selector-8">
            <img src="modal/cortinas/9.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cortina">
          </a></li>

          <li class="hvr-pulse-grow mix category-2" data-cat="2"> <a id="carousel-selector-9">
            <img src="modal/cortinas/10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cortina">
          </a></li>
          <li class="gap"></li>

            </ul>
        
    </div>
```

(Existem outros elementos, mas não estão relacionados com o problema, são mais estéticos)

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: O teu jsFiddle não tem jQuery... e acho que não aparece nada por causa do `display: none;`... podes corrigir o jsFiddle e indicar o que devia acontecer?

Comment: Na parte de HTML estou incluindo o Jquery via CDN, o plugin funcionaria como neste exemplo: http://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/lqnah